# Water restriction when washing machine is running

Tags: water

I live in a townhome. Only when the washing machine is running I'm not able to use water anywhere in the house.

As soon as it washing machine stops the water works immediately. I believe its a valve or something that stops the pressure to save on the water bill. I attached a picture of a valve I see:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does that valve cut off other than the washing machine?  Unless you have system pressure issues you shouldn't get a big pressure drop on the 1 inch line from the 1/2 inch line running, but you could get a significant pressure drop on the other 1/2" line off that same valve.

Comment: That appears to be a regular cutoff valve and it appears to be closed or almost closed.  If those half inch lines feed your whole house, the nearly closed valve would be a problem.  A valve is open when the handle is parallel to the pipe.

Comment: That is a very manual valve. There's nothing automatic happening there when the washing machine starts. I think @KH has the right answer.

Comment: The washing machine only draws water for a couple minutes during its cycle.  Please be more specific about when & how long you lose pressure to the rest of the house's fixtures.

Answer (score 2):

Open the valve and see if it makes a difference. I would think any 2 faucets on at the same time would have the same effect. The valve may have been installed to dampen water hammer issues. I have seen this done and work but it limits the flow.